# CPU wont boot when warm or hot

Tags: boot, lenovo-laptop, overheating

I have a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro, and as of late it began taking a long time to boot. It can go anywhere between 20 seconds to 5 hours. I did some tests: SSD and RAM tests find no issues, which is kind of frustrating because I think it may have had something to do with the motherboard, but now I don't know what kind of issue I'm working with.

The only lead I have right now is this connection between laptop temperature and boot time. The laptop will do a cold boot (like, if its off and had time tor est). But if the laptop is warm or hot (e.g., warm boot from the process of restarting) it would take too long for comfort. What is up with this? Any suggestions would be really useful. Thanks!

**A description of my experience booting my computer**: I would turn on the computer, and I would get a black screen, and after the 20 seconds or 5 hours I get the Lenovo logo and then the Windows OS. Once the OS runs its like a normal computer and I cant detect anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: Can you find diag boot disk and see if it stays booted to it when the CPU is hot? How about CMOS/BIOS setup screen staying on when the CPU is hot?

Comment: Make sure you have removed all external devices plugged in to it and try it for a while.

Comment: I have removed all the external devices and that hasn't done the trick, unfortunately. I have had the CMOS/BIOS setup screen stay on for a bit so the CPU did get hot. It was on for a bit primarily because it was my first time exploring the BIOS on this particular laptop. It did not turn off. I even ended up running Lenovo's full hardware scan and nothing wrong(frustrating)...However, I have learned that on hibernate the CPU turns on quicker, and while the computer was still cool I was able to immediately restart with better ease.